# What is the Tinkerpop equivalent of Neo4j match/join on property values

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a `Neo4j` `Cypher` query. I am trying to understand how to do the same query in `Tinkerpop`/`Gremlin` (not `Neo4j` implementation).

```
start
  f=node:node_auto_index('_Element:field OR _Element:dynamicField'),
  t=node:node_auto_index(_Element = 'fieldType')
where
  f.type=t.name
return
  f, t
```

Basically, I get two types of nodes (labels/types/whatever) and try to find where one points to another via property value match. I'll then create a real relationship using the results.

The graph is not very large, up to several thousand nodes.

Comment: i'm not so good at cypher, so to answer your question i'd need to clarify something.  are you just trying to match any vertex to any other vertex in the graph on some arbitrary property and then add an edge between the two?

Comment: Basically, yes. Like SQL join. In this case specifically, I also select the original vertexes on each side based on another (_Element) property value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything there are lots of ways to approach this.  Since you have a small dataset, I didn't think it would be a problem to do lookups over `g.V` within the Gremlin pipeline.  To simulate your problem, I created my own:  Using the [toy graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Defining-a-Property-Graph), add a `sameFirstLetter` edge to any vertex that had a `lang` property to any vertex that had an `age` property and where the first letter of their respective `name` properties was the same.  In this case, it should add two vertices, from 5 to 4 and from 3 to 4.

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()                                                                  
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.has('lang').transform{v->[v,g.V.has('age').filter{it.name.startsWith(v.lang[0])}.toList()]}.sideEffect{edgeList->edgeList[1].each{it.each{edgeList[0].addEdge('sameFirstLetter',it)}}}
==>[v[3], [v[4]]]
==>[v[5], [v[4]]]
gremlin> g.E
==>e[1][5-sameFirstLetter->4]
==>e[10][4-created->5]
==>e[0][3-sameFirstLetter->4]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
==>e[11][4-created->3]
==>e[12][6-created->3]
```

There are two pieces to this code.  The first constructs an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) of matches and the second creates the edge.  Here's the part that gets the adjacency list:

```
g.V.has('lang').transform{v->[v,g.V.has('age').filter{it.name.startsWith(v.lang[0])}.toList()]}
```

The above code basically says, grab all vertices that have a `lang` property (note that this use of `has` is part of the latest version of Gremlin - the soon to be released 2.4.0.  Prior to 2.4.0 you could do `.hasNot('lang',null)` or something similar) and then convert them to a list where the first item in the list is the `lang` vertex and the second item in the list is a list of vertices in the graph that match on the first letter of `name` with the first letter of `lang` (in this case the letter `j` for both `lang` vertices).

```
.sideEffect{edgeList->edgeList[1].each{it.each{edgeList[0].addEdge('sameFirstLetter',it)}}}
```

The above sideEffect is processing this output...the adjacency list:

```
==>[v[3], [v[4]]]
==>[v[5], [v[4]]]
```

This operation could be performed as a separate line of code (not all Gremlin needs to be written in a single line...as satisfying as that may be).  You could simply store the adjacency list to a variable then post-process it to create the edges.  In any case, I chose to use `sideEffect` here, where I loop the list of lists creating edges as I go.

Alternatively, you could also make two passes through the dataset by building up an in-memory index keyed on the property value and then use that as a lookup to build the adjacency list.  In this way you would only suffer two passes through the the vertex list:

```
gremlin> m=g.V.groupBy{it.name[0]}{it}.cap.next()
==>v=[v[2]]
==>r=[v[5]]
==>p=[v[6]]
==>l=[v[3]]
==>m=[v[1]]
==>j=[v[4]]
gremlin> g.V.has('lang').transform{[it,m[it.lang[0]]]}
==>[v[3], [v[4]]]
==>[v[5], [v[4]]]
```

This gets you to the same adjacency list as found in the previous example.  Edge creation via the adjacency list is still the performed as previously noted.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I am still working through it. The trick seems to be that *transform* allows to keep one variable while introducing secondary iterator at the same time. Is it more computationally efficient than getting two vertices from Gremlin and then doing matching in external (Java) code?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.  Your graph is sufficiently small that there are many options.  The second approach to getting the adjacency list of new edges to add, constructs an in-memory index of property values that will be matched against.  In this fashion, only two passes are made through the vertex list.

Comment: Thank you. That's plenty of material to dig into for now.